# Prevent Usage of generated Initializer in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I want to prevent the use of the standard Xcode generated Initializer for a CoreData ManagedObject, because I want to wire some things up myself.
My plan was to write a Factory or a special Initializer.

I tried to make the Xcode generated Initializer private in an extension and provide another Initializer, that uses this private.
Unfortunately that doesn't compile.

```
extension Item {
  private init(context : NSManagedObjectContext?){   // NOT ALLOWED !!
    self.init(context: context)
  }
  
  static func ItemFactory(i: Int)-> Item{
    let moc = PersistenceController.moc
    let item = Item(context: moc)
    // do some Initialisation
    item.i = I
    return item
  }
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You have a subclass of NSManagedObject so you need to override the init (using the `override` keyword) but notice that this is a convenience init and the one you should be concerned with is [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506357-init). That being said, you can’t change the access level but you could perhaps add a fatalError to the overridden init to stop it from being used. Main question though in my opinion, is it worth it?

Comment: Tnx @JoakimDanielson, One question: why does TestEntity(context: moc) call init(entity:insertInto:)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How can I create an Instance of this ManagedObject, if I let the overridden init fail with a fatalError

Comment: Because it is the designated (default) init. I think the best idea is to forget the whole thing, you are trying to build a complicated solution for little gain. A soft solution that I used in a similar situation was to use a linter like swiftlint and create a custom rule that generate a warning if the init is being used.